# How to cycle through a list and add one item to each tuple in a list of tuples using 'zip()'?

Tags: python, python-zip

My data file contains eight thousand lines, where each line is a tuple. The first two lines are:

```
(2000, 1, 1, 1, 336)
(2000, 1, 1, 2, 335)
```

I would like to repeatedly cycle through the weekdays and append a weekday to each data tuple. The list of lines should look like:

```
[(2000, 1, 1, 1, 336, 'Sat'), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 335, 'Sun'), ...]
```

I've tried different approaches, and have managed to get almost every possible combination except the desired one. I can't quite wrap my head around what I've misunderstood.

#### Code

```python
weekdays = ['Sat','Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri']    
a = read_file('VIK_sealevel_2000.txt')
zipp = list(zip(a, weekdays))
print(zipp[0:2])
```

#### Output

```
[((2000, 1, 1, 1, 335), 'Sat'), ((2000, 1, 1, 2, 336), 'Sun')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is how to efficiently cycle through the weekdays. A clean solution is to use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

The following will generate an infinite sequence of repeating weekdays.

```
import itertools

weekdays = ['Sat','Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri']
itertools.cycle(weekdays)
```

The [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function will stop when the shortest input iterable is exhausted. Now that we have an infinite sequence of weekdays, the shortest input will be the eight thousand lines of data.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> weekdays = ['Sat','Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri']
>>> data = [(2000, 1, 1, 1, 336), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 335), (2000, 1, 1, 1, 334), 
            (2000, 1, 1, 2, 333), (2000, 1, 1, 1, 332), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 331), 
            (2000, 1, 1, 1, 330), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 329), (2000, 1, 1, 1, 328), 
            (2000, 1, 1, 2, 327)]
>>> list(zip(data, itertools.cycle(weekdays)))
[((2000, 1, 1, 1, 336), 'Sat'), ((2000, 1, 1, 2, 335), 'Sun'), 
 ((2000, 1, 1, 1, 334), 'Mon'), ((2000, 1, 1, 2, 333), 'Tue'), 
 ((2000, 1, 1, 1, 332), 'Wed'), ((2000, 1, 1, 2, 331), 'Thu'), 
 ((2000, 1, 1, 1, 330), 'Fri'), ((2000, 1, 1, 2, 329), 'Sat'), 
 ((2000, 1, 1, 1, 328), 'Sun'), ((2000, 1, 1, 2, 327), 'Mon')]
```

Lastly, to get the weekday inside the inner tuples, we can create new tuples within a list comprehension.

```
>>> [t + (day,) for t, day in zip(data, itertools.cycle(weekdays))]
[(2000, 1, 1, 1, 336, 'Sat'), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 335, 'Sun'), 
 (2000, 1, 1, 1, 334, 'Mon'), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 333, 'Tue'), 
 (2000, 1, 1, 1, 332, 'Wed'), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 331, 'Thu'), 
 (2000, 1, 1, 1, 330, 'Fri'), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 329, 'Sat'), 
 (2000, 1, 1, 1, 328, 'Sun'), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 327, 'Mon')]
```

Here, `t` is the tuple associated with each line of data, `day` is the weekday, and the syntax `t + (day,)` creates a new tuple formed by combining the data tuple with the weekday.

Answer (score 1):

To add the weekday into each tuple, try using:

```py
a = [(2000, 1, 1, 1, 335), (2000, 1, 1, 2, 336)] # was read_file('VIK_sealevel_2000.txt')
weekdays = ['Sat','Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri']
zipp = [row[0] + (row[1],) for row in zip(a, weekdays)]
```

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64437029/3230133) by Christopher Peisert, this answer is incorrect when there are more rows in `a` than in `weekdays`